# Не получается в проекте на Yii2 обновить версия PHP

Tags: php, yii2, vagrant

не получается обновить версию PHP до 7.2 в проекте на Yii2. Виртуальную машину поднял на вагрант. В самом проекте phpinfo() выдает такой результат: [image: phpinfo()]

На самой машине PHP 7.2.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar  7 2019 20:23:06) ( NTS )

После ввода команд
sudo service php7.0-fpm stop
sudo service php7.2-fpm start

Выдает такую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка]

sudo service nginx reload и 
sudo service nginx restart
Не помогают, после перезагрузки машины все то же самое. Уже всю голову сломал, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю

Comment: а логи nginx что говорят?

Comment: Решил проблему, ошибка была в настройках nginx, не та версия стояла